# A number is inserted, and I have to make a message box pop up with the word versions of the numbers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I fix this program? A number is inserted, and I have to make a message box pop up with the word versions of the numbers. For example, if "301" is typed in, the message box has to say "Three Zero One". Here's what I have:

```
string display = "";            
for (int i = 0; i < txtNumber.Text.Length; i++)
{
    if (txtNumber.Text[i] == 0)
    {
        display += "Zero ";
    }

    if (txtNumber.Text[i] == 1)
    {
        display += "One ";
    }

    if (txtNumber.Text[i] == 2)
    {
        display += "Two ";
    }

    if (txtNumber.Text[i] == 3)
    {
        display += "Three ";
    }

    if (txtNumber.Text[i] == 4)
    {
        display += "Four ";
    }

    if (txtNumber.Text[i] == 5)
    {
        display += "Five ";
    }

    if (txtNumber.Text[i] == 6)
    {
        display += "Six ";
    }

    if (txtNumber.Text[i] == 7)
    {
        display += "Seven ";
    }

    if (txtNumber.Text[i] == 8)
    {
        display += "Eight ";
    }

    if (txtNumber.Text[i] == 9)
    {
        display += "Nine ";
    }               
}

MessageBox.Show(display);
```

There are no errors showing up on an error list, but whenever I run it and type in a number and hit enter, the message box pops up with nothing in it. Anything will help. Thank you very much!

Comment: you are comparing string against and int

Comment: @JuanC. _Actually_, he is comparing `char` against `int` in his if statements.. `.Text[i]` is `char`, not `string`.

Answer (score 1):

`Text[i]` is a character that is being converted automatically to `int`. And since for example `'0'` code is not 0 - nothing is shown. Change all your `if` to char-to-char comparison:

```
if (txtNumber.Text[i] == '0')
```

Also you might want to consider using `switch` construction.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numToText = new Dictionary<int, string>() { {'0', "Zero "}, ...};
foreach (var char in txtMessage.Text)
{
    display += numToText[char];
}
```

This is probly also a linq one-liner

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are comparing characters with integers, which you cannot do.
However, you can do like this:

```
foreach (char c in txtNumber.Text)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case '0': display += "Zero ";
            break;
        case '1': display += "One ";
            break;
        case '2': display += "Two ";
            break;
        case '3': display += "Three ";
            break;
        case '4': display += "Four ";
            break;
        case '5': display += "Five ";
            break;
        case '6': display += "Six ";
            break;
        case '7': display += "Seven ";
            break;
        case '8': display += "Eight ";
            break;
        case '9': display += "Nine ";
            break;
        default: display += "NaN ";
            break;
    }
}
```

Here we loop through all the characters in the string and compares each character with a specified case in the switch statement and if the character is neither 0-9 it dispays "NaN" (Not a Number).

Answer (score 0):

The .Text property is of type string. Indexing into an item of type string returns values of type char. Your code is performing an incorrect implied cast the way that it's written now. For example, casting a 0 char to an int yields 48 and casting 0 int to a char yields an ASCII NUL. Try either single-quoting your digits to make them character literals (i.e. `'0'`) or parsing the indexed item (i.e., `int.Parse(txtNumber.Text[i])`) to avoid an implied cast with an unexpected result.

Comment: FYI parsing is often the better way to go when taking user input as it can help prevent certain types of potential attacks against your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `char` with `int` in your `txtNumber.Text[i] == 0` line for example.

And since I'm an [humble programmer](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD340.html), I wrote your example with based [*switch stament*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) on [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) like;

```
void Main()
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    string result = "";
    foreach (var i in s)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case '1':
                result += "One ";
                break;
            case '2':
                result += "Two ";
                break;
            case '3':
                result += "Three ";
                break;
            case '4':
                result += "Four ";
                break;
            case '5':
                result += "Five ";
                break;
            case '6':
                result += "Six ";
                break;
            case '7':
                result += "Seven ";
                break;
            case '8':
                result += "Eight ";
                break;
            case '9':
                result += "Nine ";
                break;
            case '0':
                result += "Zero ";
                break;
        }
    }
    result = result.Trim();
    result.Dump();
}
```

For `301` as an input, output will be `Three Zero One`

Answer (score 0):

Should be as easy as

```
public static string DigitsToWords( string digits )
{
  if ( !digits.All( char.IsDigit ) ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("digits");

  return string.Join( " " , digits.Select( d => words[d-'0'] ) ) ;
}
private static readonly string [] words = { "zero" , "one" , "two" , "three" , "four" , "five" , "six" , "seven" , "eight" , "nine" , } ;
```